# How to get prettyprint to work on dynamically generated dom element

Tags: javascript, pretty-print

I'm using [prettyprint](http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html) plugin as syntax highlighter, it work fine when page loads but when i add new elements dynamically it doesn't work! I tried using `prettyPrint()` to invoke it after loading the new contents but it didn't work! i also followed the instructions on the plugin website by wrapping `prettyPrint()` with a function but it didn't work neither! any help would be much appreciated.
i installed the plugin like this:

```
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
```

my code is:

```
function showCode(e){
    (e.preventDefault) ? e.preventDefault() : e.returnValue = false;
    var parent = document.createElement('div'),
        pre = document.createElement('pre'),
        code = document.createElement('code'),
        elm = (e.currentTarget) ? e.currentTarget : e.srcElement,
        src = elm.getAttribute('href'),
        id = elm.getElementsByTagName('img')[0].getAttribute('src').replace(/images\/(.+?)\.png/g, "$1");
    parent.id = "codeZoom";
    pre.className = "prettyprint linenums lang-" + id;

    var xhr = (window.XMLHttpRequest) ? new window.XMLHttpRequest() : new activeXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    xhr.open('get', src, true);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function()
    {
        if(xhr.readyState == 4 && xhr.status == 200)
        {
            var text = document.createTextNode(xhr.responseText);
            code.appendChild(text);
            pre.appendChild(code);
            parent.appendChild(pre);
            document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(parent);
            center(parent);
            prettyPrint();
        }
    }
}
```

currently i'm getting the error message prettyPrint is not defined.

Comment: You need to show some context. If it says `prettyPrint` is not defined then it is because it is not defined! Impossible to know with your current code

Comment: I added the link to the plugin website, it's supposed to create `prettyPrint` function when page loads which i think it does because it works on other `pre` elements when page starts!

Comment: but it says here: http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html that i can (scroll to the end of the page), no?

Comment: That doesn't apply when you are using the loader (run_prettify.js) as far as I can see

Comment: I see that you can reach the `prettyPrint` function by using the undocumented `PR. prettyPrint()` function. Although, it is safer if you stop using the loader and use `prettyPrint()` instead. Let me know if this is your case

Comment: it says `PR.prettyPrint()` is not a function

Comment: looks like i needed to include another file which i still don't understand why but it works, thanks for all your help

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As far as I can tell your code seems correct.

1) include pretty print **( not the run_xxx) version**

2) call prettyPrint() any time your Dom is updated

However your script that includes prettyPrint is missing a closing ", so maybe it's just a typo your problem :)

Comment: how do i inclue pretty print? do i have to download it to my server?

Comment: No just follow steps on 
http://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/README.html and be sure to add a CSS class of prettyPrint to whatever you want prettified. Nothing really else needed.

Comment: Actually yes you do need to download it, or find a cdn version of it... It's the 1st thing said in the above doc page. I use it on my site at www.i-technology.net go there and look at the source to see how I referenced it. I'm on an iPad right now so can't help much but if I remember right I referenced some cdn version on there.

Comment: in the first step it says download a distribution! what do i do with it after that?

Comment: Unzip it into a directory of your choice and reference it like you would jQuery or any other lib in your site

Comment: i downloaded the min version and included prettify.js and it worked :) but i don't understand what's the other link `run_prettify` for thogh?

Comment: Don't know, you'd have to look at the source to see what it does. Also be sure to reference the CSS files you need for syntax highlighting

Answer (score 5):

When prettyprint() executes, it adds the class "prettyprinted" to the container element.  I guess so that its not pretty printed twice, probably breaks things.

You just need to remove that class before running prettyprint() again.

```
$('#my_element').removeClass('prettyprinted');
prettyPrint();
```

Comment: up voted as this is the correct answer. Must remove class prior to calling prettyPrint(). May also be done with plain javascript: element.classList.remove("prettyprinted").