# How to re-apply prettyPrint AFTER run_prettify.js has been loaded

Tags: javascript, pretty-print

I'm trying with Javascript code prettifier, and come up with a question.

If I do not assign `class="prettyprint"` to `<pre>` in static html, but wish to apply prettyprint later(e.g, when user click on a "colorize" button on my webpage), **how can I achieve this?**

Slightly modifying original run_prettify.js or prettify.js is acceptable, because I'm going to put this to offline use.

My experiment:

Writing try-delay-class.html:

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://google-code-prettify.googlecode.com/svn/loader/run_prettify.js"></script>
</head>
See it:
<pre>
class Voila {
public:
  // Voila
  static const string VOILA = "Voila";

  // will not interfere with embedded <a href="#voila1">tags</a>.
}
</pre>
</html>
```

Open in Chrome v26, bring up the console, execute:

```
pres=document.getElementsByTagName('pre')
pres[0].className+=" prettyprint"
```

Syntax color does not come up.

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

According to a comment found here, [How to get prettyprint to work on dynamically generated dom element](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15742551/151453) , I find the way out. Just call:

```
PR.prettyPrint()
```

BTW: If you want to remove code color highlight, you cannot simply set pre's class to empty followed by `PR.prettyPrint()` again. `PR.prettyPrint()` can only attach color tags but not remove them. A feasible way to do that is saving your original `<pre>` content before applying prettyprint, then restore `<pre>`s content later. Verified in my post [jQuery, how to clone back saved elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16147598/jquery-how-to-clone-back-saved-elements) .

[image]

Comment: When PR.prettyPrint() is run, it adds the "prettyprinted" class to each element it changes. If you need to reapply prettyPrint to a <pre>, remove the "prettyprinted" class first, then call PR.prettyPrint()

Answer (score 1):

You can find three examples [here](https://github.com/google/code-prettify/issues/268)

I did it as follows in js:

```
document.getElementById('outputa').innerHTML = 
 PR.prettyPrintOne("your code in brackets or your variable (without these brackets)",
 'java');
```