# jQuery, how to clone back saved elements?

Tags: jquery

To demonstrate, please see my html :

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
See it:
<pre>
print "Say hello"
</pre>
<p><b>==SEP==</b></p>
<pre>
class Voila {
public:
  // Voila
  static const string VOILA = "Voila";

  // will not interfere with embedded <a href="#voila1">tags</a>.
}
</pre>
</html>
```

In Chrome v26 console, I execute:

```
var pres_orig=$('pre').clone()
$('pre').replaceWith('<pre>spam</pre>')
```

**Then my question: How to clone back the `<pre>` content from saved pres_orig so that my page displays its original content?**

I've tried the following which does not work:

```
$('pre').replaceWith(pres_orig)
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Why not just store the inner HTML and then change that, rather than changing the actual `pre` element. like this: `var orig = $("pre").html(); $("pre").html("spam");` and then `$("pre").html(orig);`

Comment: Does not work as expected. Have you tried it yourself? in which browser, which version?

Comment: It works fine, [see here](http://jsfiddle.net/JfW8R/)

Comment: Not fine. Please try with two <pre>s. Using your code, they will both get replaced with the same content.

Comment: Well yeah, or course they will. I was assuming you would know about using the selectors if you need to be more specific. I would suggest you use an `id` for the exact one you need to reference

Comment: [How about this?](http://jsfiddle.net/JfW8R/1/)... I will make it into an answer for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I find the best solution up to now, only one statement:

```
for(var i=0; i<pres_orig.length; i++) 
    $('pre').eq(i).replaceWith(pres_orig.eq(i).clone());
```

OR

```
$('pre').each( function(i){ 
    $(this).replaceWith(pres_orig.eq(i).clone()) 
});
```

NOTE: using clone() so that `pres_orig` remains its standalone copy, so that we are able to clone it back any amount of times.

[image]

Comment: I would be better if ``replaceWith`` is replaced with something like``copyFrom``, so I can omit ``clone``.

Answer (score 1):

As you have multiple `pre` elements with no identifying value. One approach you could take is to loop all the elements and store the inner html in an array. Then when you need to load them again, you can loop them and pull the array html using the index.

Something like this:

```
//store all the data on load
var storage = [];
$("pre").each(function(){
   storage.push($(this).html()); 
});

//set the new html to "spam"
$("pre").html("spam");

//reload the original data
$("pre").each(function(index){
    $(this).html(storage[index]);
});
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/JfW8R/1/)

Comment: Thank you. This one meets my expectation. +1 from me.

Answer (score 0):

Don't clone. Save inner (or outer) HTML. Insert inner HTML into pre. Use .html() to get inner HTML and .html(content) to replace inner HTML.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(function() {
        var pres = [];
        // this is how you store it:
        $('pre').each(function(i) {
          pres[i] = $(this).html();
        });
        // this is how you restore it:
        $('pre').each(function(i) {
          $(this).html(pres[i] + "SPAM ;)");
        });
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    See it:
    <pre>
      print "Say hello"
    </pre>
    <p><b>==SEP==</b></p>
    <pre>
      class Voila {
      public:
        // Voila
        static const string VOILA = "Voila";

        // will not interfere with embedded <a href="#voila1">tags</a>.
      }
    </pre>
  </body>
</html>
```

So, if you want to save this array to a file or cookie, use [JSON3](https://github.com/bestiejs/json3) to serialize it.

Comment: What is the advantage of doing this?

Comment: You get serializable data, it's simple, it's easy to modify text content.